# Possible to flush results back through an asmx web service?

Tags: web-services, asmx

I have an asmx web service that performs 5 tasks.

It is at all possible to send back a result during the call, so that when 1 task completes, even though the web service is still running, the client can get some results back before the whole web service method completes all its work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. ASMX web services use a request/response mechanism. One request - one response.